# AngularJS Show just filtered Items in table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

Is possible to hide the result of this table and just show the filtered result?

```html
<table class="table table-responsive"
       ng-class="{'table-striped':!spinnerVisible}">
    <thead class="thead-inverse">
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" value="selected"
                       ng-model="checkboxes.checkAll"
                       ng-click="checkAllRows()"></th>
            <th>SID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Pathway</th>
            <th>Advisor</th>
            <th>Credits</th>
            <th>Campus</th>
            <th ng-if="isPathwayLead">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr ng-repeat="s in searchData.students
                     |orderBy:'lastName' 
                     |filter:search
                     |range:selectedPage:pageSize"
        student-row>
    </tr>
</table>
```

By default the page load a list of students like this

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I would like to hide this list and just show the result of the filter above!
is that possible?

Student row

```
<tr ng-class="{awesome:s.selected}">
<td><input name="checker" type="checkbox" value="selected" ng-model="s.selected"></td>
<td><a class="clickableAwesomeFont" ng-click="toStudent(s.sid)">{{s.sid}}</a></td>
<td>{{s.lastName.trim() + ', ' + s.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{s.pathwayName + (s.subPathwayName ? ', ' + s.subPathwayName : '')}}</td>
<td>{{s.advisorName}}</td>
<td>{{s.credits}}</td>
<td>{{s.branchCodeDescription}}</td>
<td ng-if="isPathwayLead"><span class="card-title fa fa-pencil-square-o pull-right clickableAwesomeFont" ng-click="popupReviewForm(s)"></span></td>
```

SearchFilter

```
<div>
    <div style="padding-top:100px;" id="mid_container" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <label for="search-term">Search</label>
                <input id="search-term" type="text" ng- 
          keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && commenceSearch()" ng- 
            model="searchModel.searchTerm"
                       class="form-control" placeholder="Name or SID" 
               aria-describedby="sizing-addon3">
                <label for="pathway_dd">Pathway</label>
                <select id="pathway_dd" class="form-control custom" ng- 
          change=onPathwayChange() ng-options="p.id as p.name for p in 
             pathways"
                        ng-model="searchModel.pathwayID">
                    <option value="">Select Pathway</option>
                </select>
                <label for="subPathway_dd">Area of Interest</label>
                <select id="subPathway_dd" class="form-control custom" ng- 
        options="sp.id as sp.name for sp in subPathways" ng- 
        model="searchModel.subPathwayID">
                    <option value="">Select Area of Interest</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
                <label for="advisor_dd">Advisor</label>
                <select id="advisor_dd" class="form-control custom" ng- 
            model="searchModel.advisorSID">
                    <option value="">Select Advisor</option>
                    <option value="noadvisor">No Advisor</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="a in advisors| orderBy:'lastName'" 
            value="{{a.sid}}">{{a.lastName + ', ' + a.firstName}}</option>
                </select>
                <label for="credit-select">Credits</label>
                <select id="credit-select" class="form-control custom" ng- 
          model="searchModel.creditID" value="c.id" ng-options="c.id as 
          c.text for c in credits" />
                <label for="campus_dd">Campus</label>
                <select id="campus_dd" class="form-control custom" ng- 
                model="searchModel.branchCode">
                    <option value="">Select Campus</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="b in branches" value=" 
          {{b.branchCode}}">{{b.description}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input ng-model="searchModel.isEnrolled" 
                    type="checkbox">Enrolled
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input ng-model="searchModel.isMandatory" 
           type="checkbox">Mandatory
                    </label>
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" ng- 
     click="commenceSearch()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" 
     title="Apply Search Filters" />&nbsp;Search</button><br />
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng-

        click="clearSearch()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" 
        title="Reset Search Filters" />&nbsp;Reset</button>
                <!--<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" ng- 
        click="toggleFilter()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" 
          title="Close Search Filter Panel" />&nbsp;Close</button>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically just want to know if i can use ng-Show just to show filtered results and hide the rest without having to changes a lot of everything

Comment: don't see angularjs controller and search filter code.

Comment: For stuff like this it is way better to do the filtering in your controller rather than as part of the `ng-repeat` directive. Especially as it looks like you want to be able to filter on the selections of multiple dropdowns as well as some text criteria.

Comment: The person that develop this system is no longer here, so I'm kinda trying to support this portal

Answer (score 3):

I am sharing the way I normally do where there's a need for searching among the grid list. I normally, take one input as a `search term` and search the entire list with the help of `$filter` in my `watcher` and if it matches with any key of the particular object, update the grid list instantly with the new filtered list.

I don't recommend copy pasting the code since I am using many custom directives and material design. But you can get the main idea how can you do it.

```
<md-toolbar style="background-color:#F57C00 !important;"
            ng-show="showSearch">
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
        <md-icon style="color:white">search</md-icon>
        <input type="text" ng-model="searchPhrase" style="color:white" name="searchPhrase">
    </md-input-container>
    <md-button ng-click="resetFilter()" class="md-icon-button">
        <md-tooltip style="background-color:lightgray;color:black" md-direction="top">close</md-tooltip>
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
    </md-button>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

in my controller I write the watcher as :

```
$scope.$watch('searchPhrase', function (keyword) {
    if (keyword!= null && keyword!= '' && keyword!= undefined)
        $scope.gridList = ($filter('filter')($scope.actualGridList, keyword)); 

    // incase keyword was empty, change the list back to original
    else 
        $scope.gridList = angular.copy($scope.actualGridList);
});

//incase reset button was pressed, change the list back to original
$scope.resetFilter = function () {
    $scope.showSearch = false;
    $scope.searchPhrase = '';
    $scope.gridList = angular.copy($scope.actualGridList);
}
```

Note that:

I am using `gridlist` as the `ng-repeat` list and not the `actualGridList`, in this way I will have the original list unmodified and `gridList` will be reflected back to what the original list is through my `resetFilter()`

If you want to filter the `searchData.students` based on many keywords, you can filter the list based on those keys, something similar to:

```
$scope.copStudents = $filter('filter')($scope.searchData.students, 
    { 'name': keyword }, true);
```